# How do you use LsaEnumerateLogonSessions in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008

In a C# Windows Forms Application, I'm trying to get a list of the users currently logged into a workstation (both local and domain users). Every search about this has led me to threads mentioning "just use [LsaEnumerateLogonSessions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378275%28VS.85%29.aspx)".

So...how do you actually use this? The MSDN page is very sparse and doesn't seem to offer any clues.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use [Cassia](http://code.google.com/p/cassia/), an open source wrapper.

```
ITerminalServicesManager manager = new TerminalServicesManager();
using (ITerminalServer server = manager.GetRemoteServer("your-server-name"))
{
    server.Open();
    foreach (ITerminalServicesSession session in server.GetSessions())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Session ID: " + session.SessionId);
        Console.WriteLine("User: " + session.UserAccount);
        Console.WriteLine("State: " + session.ConnectionState);
        Console.WriteLine("Logon Time: " + session.LoginTime);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how this will handle domain users; try it in LINQPad.

To answer your question, you need to declare it as a P/Invoke method that takes an `out in` and an `out long[]`.

Comment: Ok, I seem to have loaded the library. Looks like I'll be working with it for a little while to familiarize myself with it. As for your comment about P/Invoke...what do I do there?

Comment: If you want to call `LsaEnumerateLogonSessions` directly without Cassia, you'll need to learn P/Invoke first.

Comment: Cassia doesn't use LsaEnumerateLogonSessions at all. It uses only WTSEnumerateSessions.