# How to detect running in Windows 10 - Windows Virtual Desktop (WVD)

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I want to be able to detect when my installer is running on a Win10 WVD OS.

- Detecting 'desktop' install: `MsiNTProductType = 1`
- Detecting 'rdsh' install: `MsiNTProductType = 3 And TerminalServer = 1`
- Detecting 'WVD' install?

Here are the pieces of data that I've got so far:

- WVD installs will set the MSI property `MsiNTProductType = 3`
- WVD installs will set the MSI property `TerminalServer = 1`
- WVD installs have `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion] "InstallationType"="Client"`

What's an appropriate way to detect WVD installs in MSI? Are there other pieces of information that I don't know about? I'd rather not rely on the registry...

Comment: It is very late for me, no time to look at this now, but lobbing some links as I call it: [Windows 10 - a version oddity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49335885/windows-10-not-detecting-on-installshield). Not a real match, but maybe skim to check for new ideas. And [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49725074/129130) you can skim for some sort of idea on detecting details for the system you run on. This last answer also not a good match (it relates to terminal servers and logged on users).

Comment: I did a quick search in WMI using [WmiExplorer.exe](https://github.com/vinaypamnani/wmie2/releases). Nothing obvious there - maybe check on a system that is actually WVD? Maybe search for **`remote`**, **`terminalserver`**, **`wvd`**, **`rdsh`**, **`etc...`**?

Comment: And to spark ideas, let's list options: **`command line?`** **`power shell (.NET)?`** **`WMI?`** **`Win32?`** **`COM?`**

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the easiest way is to key off the registry value:


`[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion]`
 `"InstallationType"="Client"`

Along with the `TerminalServer` MSI property.